# How do I find next available column in Xls file and write there using xlrd/xlwt in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xlwt

I am writing a selenium script where I need to store username password information of all the accounts I am creating.
So I am using xlrd and xlwt to write information in an excel file but I am not able to find a way how script automatically detects next available row in the sheet and writes the info there. I am very new to Python.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the number of rows and append information like this:

```
file = xlrd.open_workbook('accounts.xls', formatting_info=True)
row_number = file.sheet_by_index(0).nrows
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0) 
sheet.write(row_number, 0, 'blabla')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @mdegis
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_index'` is the error I am getting. I am adding following libs.
`from xlrd import *
from xlutils.copy import copy
from xlwt import *
import os.path`

Can you tell me what am I missing